# How to handle Token expiration and regeneration during load test in Loadrunner?

Tags: token, refresh, loadrunner

Tokens is getting generated for every 10 minutes how handle this in load testing using loadrunner tool.

I have used for loop, each iteration will take one minute to complete business functionality, so I have given 10 iteration in loop after that it will call login again getting the new token, in load testing 3 iteration it self taking 10 mins time
4th iteration is getting failed how to handle this scenario without failing the script because of token got expired

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the script where you get the token?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.